# Database independent grouped count distinct "days ago" in Rails 6

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-6

I want to find out on how many different 24 hour intervals a word occurred (note that the actual application is different and more complicated, but this is equivalent and needs no context).

I could do that with an SQL query like this in Postgresql:

```sql
SELECT
  word,
  COUNT(DISTINCT FLOOR(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM AGE(created_at)) / 86400)) AS num_distinct_days_with_occurrence
FROM word_occurrences
GROUP BY word
```

I even managed to write Rails code that generates this query:

```rb
WordOccurrence.select(:word).group(:word).distinct.count('FLOOR(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM AGE(created_at)) / 86400)')
```

However, it doesn't work in Sqlite3 with the same code.

I guess if I put in some time, I could probably also find a way to make it work in Sqlite3, but I can't figure out how to get **both** to work. I saw the count API had more features in past rails versions, but I think even that wouldn't be enough given that my main problem is timestamp handling and not counting. Also, I couldn't figure out where these features went in Rails 6.

Is there a way to make this work for both adapters? And if not, what is the best way to handle such snippets of database dependent code and choose the right one?

Example data:

```
[
  { word: 'a', created_at: '2020-01-10 22:30' },
  { word: 'a', created_at: '2020-01-10 23:30' },
  { word: 'a', created_at: '2020-01-11 22:30' },
  { word: 'b', created_at: '2020-01-10 22:30' }
]
```

If I query this at 2020-04-08, I should get this result:

```
[
  { word: 'a', num_distinct_days_with_occurrence: 2 },
  { word: 'b', num_distinct_days_with_occurrence: 1 }
]
```

Comment: Can you give example data?

Comment: Added some example data in JSON format